# Wheres my misstep?

Tags: calculus

Using the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus to solve the initial value problem with $f(1)=3$, and $dy/dx = 2x + 1$, then $y = \int\limits_1^x (2t + 1) dt + C$ and then $C = 3$. However we know that the integral of $dy/dx = 2x + 1$ is $y=x^2 + x + C$ and plugging in $x=1$ and $y=3$ then $C=1$.

I get two solutions for C, C=3 with the FTC and C=1 from oldfashioned calculus

Obviously there is a fallacy so could someone tell me what I did wrong?

Comment: Why is there obviously a fallacy? Your solution is correct.

Comment: $f=y$? i suppose...

Comment: One problem, if nothing more, is that $y = \int\limits_1^x 2x + 1 dx + C$ doesn't make sense.

Comment: For stress, write $y=\int_1^x (2t+1) dt +C$, 'll be more clear!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you specify the integral with lower limit $1$ you have to evaluate $t^2+t$ at $t=1$ as well as $t=x$. Since the value at $t=1$ is equal to $2$, the integral comes out as $x^2+x-2$ and allows you to recover $C=3$.

The value of the formula you get for the integral should come out as zero when $x=1$ (reality check) because then the upper and lower limits are equal.

Léo is right - you should use a dummy variable like $t$ for the integrand, which would help to avoid confusion.

You are using $C$ to mean two different things. Different values of $C$ arise from different choices for the lower limit of the integral.

Comment: What do you mean by "recover 3?"

Comment: @jd123 I mean that if your function is expressed as $f(x)=x^2+x-2+C$ then the boundary condition gives $C=3$